# Maximum Value of Poisson Probability

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

What is the meaning of the Maximum Value of a Poisson distribution graph - this is a hypothetical exercise whereby the Poisson function is assumed continuous? If I say, the maximum Poisson probability that a terror attack happens increase throughout the last 5 decades, what is the significance of this? 
Thanks!

Comment: How do you need continuity to have maximum value?

Comment: It means (the number of attacks that is most likely) increases throughout the last 5 decades.